Ping OAuth Token Validation
I am using Ping OAuth authentication for some custom APIs endpoint. We have get token API
https://example.com/auth/as/token.oauth2  for external services to get token and make call to our custom API endpoints. They sent token in header which we can extract in authorizer function.
Once, we received the token in header, I want to validate the token before allowing API to do anything in backend.
As per documentation: https://docs.pingidentity.com/r/en-us/developer/vob1601508086858 I have tried to make another API call to same endpoint as above i.e. https://example.com/auth/as/token.oauth2 to validate the token but not getting expected output.
passing below body and header:
    payload = 'client_id=dummyclient&client_secret=Dummypass&grant_type=urn%3Apingidentity.com%3Aoauth2%3Agrant_type%3Avalidate_bearer&token=Tokenabc'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Cookie': 'PF=1234'
}

getting below response
    {
    "error": "unauthorized_client"
}

can someone help on how token validation works?
